# Andengine setNegativeButton (cancel), Not calling update method immediately

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using andengine... I override back key in my game..

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
             //coding 

         gameBool=true;

new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Warning!").setMessage(
                        "Are you sure you want to quit?").setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                          //coding
                         //finish activity

                    }



                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //gameBool=false;


                    }
                }).show();

           break;
      }
```

}

When press cancel button after some 5 seconds only update method get call. its not calling immeditely. Plz let me know Whats problem and how to fix this issue ? .  **The game apk size is 11mb and loading many images.. any memory issues** ?

```
  @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
             if(!gameBool)
                 {
                   //Game code //Its working fine in game play .. but when press back key and cancel means. its calling after 5 sec only.. not immediately
                }


        }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you do when you press the cancel button. But you might be doing some heavy processing or not using a thread could be the issue here.

Comment: yes ..having many images& sprites in game play

Comment: Do one thing Do this unloading or removal in an Asynctask or thread and close your actvity immidiately

Comment: no. in game play need to handle back key

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you doing when pressed cancel button?